# multi-language website in ASP.NET Core using a list and cookie

Tags: list, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, multilingual, asp.net-core-6.0

I need to have a multi language website using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC supporting English, Spanish and Arabic using cookies and list but I don't want to use `.resx` files. I have no idea where to start or what I should do. Please help

Comment: I think use cookie instead of `.resx` is not a good idea, Because cookie will expire. Maybe you can try to save the different language into database, But i think it is more complex than using `.resx` file.

Comment: please can give me more information in details how to do it

Comment: Please the [Ms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/make-content-localizable?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://www.ezzylearning.net/tutorial/asp-net-core-localization-from-database) about how to achieve it with Database.